# JAVA - 'Provider "C" not installed' Error cant fix :(

Tags: java, exception, path, uri

I have a problem, I met this error and could not fix it :( Any Help pls ?

```
 try {
         Path p3 = Paths.get(URI.create("C:/Users/User/Desktop")); //This line is causing the error
         writeToExcell(jTable,p3);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(AutomaticReOrder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
```

The error is this:

```
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "C" not installed
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:147)
    at Products.AutomaticReOrder.jButton1ActionPerformed(AutomaticReOrder.java:130)
    at Products.AutomaticReOrder.access$000(AutomaticReOrder.java:36)
    at Products.AutomaticReOrder$2.actionPerformed(AutomaticReOrder.java:96)
    at .......
```

Comment: BDW I'm trying to use Apace to write on excel files for the first time using java and Netbeans IDE

Comment: [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html#create) on creating paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `URI.create` method expects a string in RFC 2396 format. Please see [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#create(java.lang.String))
The string `"C:/Users/User/Desktop"` is invalid.

Comment: How should I correct it pls , so i acess the Desktop on the local disk.
because i couldn't understand how it works

Comment: You can do it as `Paths.get("C:/Users/User/Desktop")`

Comment: Fixed Thanks alot :) ! But still acess denied now :(

Comment: What's inside that `writeToExcell`?

Comment: Also please confirm you have necessary permissions on the file and its not being used by any other application.

Comment: Problem Solved Thanks All :)